# Saving Datetime Immutable object as Datetime in database with Symfony and Doctrine without default comment

Tags: mysql, symfony, datetime, doctrine

I'm building the Symfony entities from the existing database dump, and decided to switch from Datetime objects to Datatime Immutable, which don't have to change anything in database. But in the migration I see that it's adding the default comment, which I want to get rid of

'ALTER TABLE application_settings CHANGE updated_at updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:datetime_immutable)'');

DB is Mysql.

Here's my Datetime Immutable property in the entity:

```
#[ORM\Column(name: 'updated_at', type: Types::DATETIME_IMMUTABLE, nullable: true)]
private ?\DateTimeImmutable $updatedAt = null;
```

Didn't find anything about this issue in the internet. Is there any way to get rid of this comment?

Comment: I think doctrine uses comment to store metadata on the field, since datetime_immutable isn't a MySQL type. But I'm not sure that's what you mean by "default comment"

Comment: This modification has no impact on the data. It just indicates for Doctrine that the data type is `datetime_immutable` and allows the library to correctly hydrate it.